# How to use one machine as master in a cluster

Tags: command-line, cloud, openssh, cluster, mathematica

I made a cluster using CSSH contains 10 machines in a network inclusive the machine that I use (currently opened machine) and the IP addresses are stored in /etc/clusters , after I opened them using:

```
cssh -M myUser factorizationcluster
```

cssh opened all of them, and it asked me to enter the password in each prompt. 
Now I need to run one command in one of them to be the master while the others are slaves... 
Is it possible and how to perform that ?